# regular try/catch block is not working with promises

Tags: javascript, asynchronous

I have an async method in a class which calls others methods from a object. So I made some errors to show  up if anything is going wrong

```js
async call(name, text, args, message, client) {
    if (this.methods.includes(name)) {
        let response = await this.components[name](
            text,
            args,
            message,
            client
        )

        response && message.reply(String(response)) 
    }

    else if (name) {
        throw Error(`${name} is not registered`)
    }

    else {
        throw Error('method call is not found')
    }
}
```

The problem is when some of these error happens the console show a bunch of unnecessary code as a "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning". I was trying use this way:

```js
try {
    await components.call(                    
        content.method,
        content.text,
        content.args,
        message,
        session
    )
}

catch {
    console.log('ignore me')
}
```

the catch above is not working, but the one below is just fine

```
components.call(                    
    content.method,
    content.text,
    content.args,
    message,
    session
).catch(e => console.log('ignore me'))
```

I know that is kind of a dumb question. It's not hard to solve, but fix the problem is not enough, I need to understand whats is happening to not repeat this later. thanks

Comment: https://catchjs.com/Docs/AsyncAwait

Comment: @RandyCasburn `catch` without binding the exception is permitted syntax

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue. Can you post a [mcve], please? How exactly is it "not working"?

Comment: @Bergi - My instinct was correct before I deleted my comment. I just looked it up after I deleted my comments. Spec is clear - without the binding, the Error object is not bound to the catch clause - therefore it is, in fact, unhandled. Definition of a handled exception is an existing binding between the handler and the Error object. That binding is only created through the use of the parameter.

Comment: @RandyCasburn But the exception still caught and does not propagate? That's what I call "handled". It does no longer cause another promise to reject.

Comment: @Bergi - yes, agree, the issue here is with `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` - a Promise rejection must be bound to the `catch` clause in order to avoid that warning. That is what the OP is experiencing.  I suppose it is the difference between a _handled_ error and a _bound_ error handler. To avoid the warning, the Error object must have a _bound_ error handler. Therefore, the `()` are required _in this case_.

Comment: @RandyCasburn "*A Promise rejection must be bound to the catch clause in order to avoid that warning.*" - where did you get that from? A promise rejection isn't "bound" at all. The promise returned by `components.call()` is marked as handled as soon as it is `await`ed. The rejection becomes an abrupt completion (exception) then, which is caught by the `try`/`catch`. It does not propagate to the `async function` (that the OP didn't show) where it would reject the returned promise, which apparently goes unhandled.

Comment: @Bergi -  [Here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-try-statement) in the first note.

Comment: @Bergi - each promise tracks if it has been handled: [Here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-properties-of-promise-instances): PromiseIsHandled.

Comment: @RandyCasburn If you refer to "*When a catch clause catches an exception, its CatchParameter is bound to that exception.*", please file an issue if you want better phrasing for catch clauses without a CatchParameter. Regarding the [[PromiseIsHandled]], as I already said, the `call()` promise is handled by the `await` and there is no other rejected promise.

Answer (score 0):

Your try catch syntax is incorrect. Syntax should be like this:

```
try {
    await components.call(                    
        content.method,
        content.text,
        content.args,
        message,
        session
    )
} catch(error) {
    console.log(error, '<<< ERROR IN HERE')
}
```